# Group By Column Name As parameter

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, group-by

Let's say that I have a table called `Sales`.

I also have a stored procedures something like this:

```
SELECT A FROM SALES GROUP BY A

SELECT B FROM SALES GROUP BY B

SELECT C FROM SALES GROUP BY C

SELECT D FROM SALES GROUP BY D

SELECT E FROM SALES GROUP BY E
```

Can I reduce the number of `SELECT` statements in that stored procedure to just one?

In other words is it possible to use the column name in group by as a parameter?

Comment: Unless you use dynamic sql, NO.

Comment: Well, you can simplify these `SELECT DISTINCT A FROM SALES` etc. Can you add more detail please

Comment: Not without switching to dynamic SQL, and then having to protect yourself against SQL Injection. If the queries really are identical, and have the same "meaning", it makes me wonder whether there should be 5 columns at all - maybe there should be a column that indicates some form of "type" that can contain A-E, and then a single column that contains the "value" (currently contained in the A-E columns) - in other words, it looks like your schema design has accidentally placed actual *data* into the column *names*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option A - you can use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT 'SELECT ' + @col + ' FROM SALES GROUP BY ' + col + '; '
EXEC (@sql)
```

Option B - you can use `CASE`

```
SELECT CASE @col WHEN 'A' THEN A
                 WHEN 'B' THEN B
                 WHEN 'C' THEN C
                 WHEN 'D' THEN D
                 WHEN 'E' THEN E
         END
FROM SALES
GROUP BY CASE @col WHEN 'A' THEN A
                   WHEN 'B' THEN B
                   WHEN 'C' THEN C
                   WHEN 'D' THEN D
                   WHEN 'E' THEN E
         END
```

(Both options receive @col as string parameter)

Answer (score 1):

Your idea breaks the stored procedure contract unless all 5 columns are compatible datatypes because the return type changes each time. This means more complex client code to deal with this return type change

If they are all the same datatype, to avoid dynamic SQL you can use this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   CASE @param
     WHEN @param = 'A' THEN A
     WHEN @param = 'B' THEN B
     WHEN @param = 'C' THEN C
     WHEN @param = 'D' THEN D
     WHEN @param = 'E' THEN E
   END
FROM
   SALES;
```

It still isn't efficient though.

If you want different aggregates like SUM or COUNT there are other ways to do this without datatype compatibility or dynamic SQL. So, what is the **actual** problem you want to solve anyway?

For example, this means you can pick A to E in the client cleanly

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COUNT(*) OVER (GROUP BY A) AS cntA,
    COUNT(*) OVER (GROUP BY B) AS cntB,
    COUNT(*) OVER (GROUP BY C) AS cntC,
    COUNT(*) OVER (GROUP BY D) AS cntD,
    COUNT(*) OVER (GROUP BY E) AS cntE
FROM
    SALES;
```